# List of reserved field handles

Tags: plugin-development, fieldtypes

Is there somewhere documented on what field handles are reserved? Would be great to have this as a resource here, especially for plugin development.

**Edit:** A good place to start would be https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/master-v2/src/records/FieldRecord.php#L24

Answer (score 5):

For those wondering, here is the link to Craft 3 reserved words:

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/ae64588a4963b06a093636be6686345bd3a9bca8/src/base/Field.php#L190

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you want to count it as "documented", but the list is in the source code repo on GitHub:

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/master-v2/src/validators/HandleValidator.php#L32

Comment: Ah! I knew there was somewhere in the codebase that listed those, thats a good start at least! :)